# Avoiding graphical "noise" when combining plots with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

I use the command `Show` to combine plots of mathematica. For instance, the code below produces the picture below. As you can see there is some "noise" where the two curves overlap. Is there a way to avoid this? I tried playing around with `Overlay`, but this did not help.

```
point = {0, 0};
angle = Pi/4;

sur[p_List] := {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[1]]^2 - p[[2]]^2};
cur[p_List, alpha_, s_] := sur[p + s*{Cos[alpha], Sin[alpha]}];
veloc[p_List, alpha_, s_] := D[cur[p, alpha, xi], xi] /. xi -> s;
acc[p_List, alpha_, s_] := D[veloc[p, alpha, xi], xi] /. xi -> s;
velocnorm[p_List, alpha_, s_] := veloc[p, alpha, s]/Norm[veloc[p, alpha, s]]
parx[p_List] := D[sur[{x, y}], x] /. {x -> p[[1]], y -> p[[2]]};
pary[p_List] := D[sur[{x, y}], y] /. {x -> p[[1]], y -> p[[2]]};
basex[p_List] := parx[p]/Norm[parx[p]];
basey[p_List] := (pary[p] - (pary[p].basex[p])*basex[p])/Norm[pary[p] -(pary[p].basex[p])*basex[p]];
gauss[p_List] := Cross[basex[p], basey[p]];
kappa[p_List, alpha_] := If[gauss[p].acc[p, alpha, 0] >= 0, Norm[Cross[veloc[p, alpha, 0],acc[p, alpha, 0]]]/Norm[veloc[p, alpha, 0]]^3, -Norm[Cross[veloc[p, alpha, 0], acc[p, alpha, 0]]]/Norm[veloc[p, alpha, 0]]^3];
tanvector[p_List, alpha_] := Cos[alpha]*basex[p] + Sin[alpha]*basey[p];
surface = ParametricPlot3D[sur[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8]]}, Mesh -> None];
tangentplaneplot[p_List] := ParametricPlot3D[sur[p] + u*basex[p] + v*basey[p], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.7]}, Mesh -> None];
normplaneplot[p_List, alpha_] := ParametricPlot3D[sur[p] + u*velocnorm[p, alpha, 0] + v*gauss[p], {u, -5, 5}, {v, -5,5}, PlotStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.7]}, Mesh -> None,Lighting -> "Neutral"];
curveplot[p_List, alpha_] := ParametricPlot3D[cur[p, alpha, s], {s, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}];
osccircleplot[p_List, alpha_] := If[kappa[p, alpha] == 0, ParametricPlot3D[sur[p] +zeta*velocnorm[p, alpha, 0], {zeta, -2, 2}],ParametricPlot3D[sur[p] + gauss[p]/kappa[p, alpha]+1/kappa[p, alpha]*(Cos[phi]*gauss[p] + Sin[phi]*velocnorm[p, alpha, 0]), {phi, 0, 2*Pi},PlotStyle -> {White, Thickness[0.005]}]];

xmin = -0.7;
xmax = 0.7;
ymin = -0.7;
ymax = 0.7;
zmin = -1;
zmax = 1;

Show[curveplot[point, angle], osccircleplot[point, angle],normplaneplot[point, angle],surface, Boxed -> False,PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}},PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Generally there are two issues, truncation error arising from discretizing the continuous model in different ways and round-off error when the GPU decides which parts of roughly coplanar polygons or collinear line segments are in front. For bad line-polygon interactions, I consider replacing `Line` with `Tube`. Sometimes, for display purposes, I offset coincident elements to force one to be in front of the other (from a particular viewpoint).  It's trickier if you want to rotate the 3D model.

Comment: I will second Michael's recommendation to convert all `Line[]` objects to `Tube[]` objects, tho choosing a tube radius is not always straightforward, and you'd need to experiment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Many thanks for the hint! There are no lines in my plot, but rather curves plotted with ParametricPlot3D, but I'll experiment with turning these curves into surfaces. That being said, could cranking up certain image parameters help? I tried increasing ImageResolution, but this does not really help.

Comment: @MichaelE2 So it turns out picking a fairly large number for PlotPoints of the two curves also helps a lot.

Comment: Curves are made up of `Line` segments, surfaces of `Polygon` objects that are usually broken down into triangles by the rendering machine. Increasing plot points shortens the line segments curves and improves the truncation error. Similarly it should make a more accurate surface. `ImageResolution` can control some qualities of rendered graphics, but probably not the issues shown in the question, which seem primarily to be issues with plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my best shot, moving the z-coord of curveplot by 0.001 and setting `Opacity[0.5]` for the white and blue line (yes, this is cheating!). This example uses an angle of Pi/10.

```
Show[Graphics3D@
   First@curveplot[point, angle] /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ, 
    z_?AtomQ} -> {x, y, z - 0.001}, osccircleplot[point, angle], 
 normplaneplot[point, angle], surface, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image]
Here is the view from the other side:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks like cheating is the way to go!